# How to run pg_dumpall in enterprisedb 9.6

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb, pg-dumpall

Need help backing up a database in enterprisedb. The pg_dumpall command doesn't work. When I run the command, it says can't connect to the database. I connect to the database and run the command, it doesn't give any errors, but the file doesn't show up in the location I saved it.

Comment: You'll have to give `pg_dumpall` the correct options so that it can connect to the database.

Comment: $ pg_dumpall > db.out this is the using dumpall command. By the way your database is in local or server?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pg_dumpall -d dbname -f outputfile`.

Or if your database is in a different server, use `pg_dumpall -h hostname -p port -U username -d dbname -f outputfile`

Comment: why should ```-d dbname``` be passed if its ```pg_dumpall```

Comment: If you are not using `postgres` user to connect, you have to specify dbname. As it creates a database process internally to dump the contents.